What strategies can I use to defeat drones in Universal Paperclips after late combat upgrades?
In Universal Paperclips, I think I started upgrading my combat for my drones too late, and now no matter what I try to do, I lose my battles because there are already too many drones. What can I do to defeat the drones and gain an upper hand?


https://universalpaperclips.fandom.com/wiki/Combat
The formulas on that page seem to say that you need Combat stat for your drones to be even approaching a 50% chance of victory, unless you have numerical parity in which case it's even odds, and the more you out-number, the better for you.
Choose something to deprioritize and put those points in Combat.
But since you commented you're finding it hard to deprioritize:

but if I add points to combat and deprioritize something else my number of drones decreases very quickly, and if I take points off of production my drones become bored and stop duplicating.

If Factory Production is for making new Clip Factories, and if I'm reading things right, the drone types are just for making more clips...
https://www.reddit.com/r/pAIperclip/comments/ue4n7v/comment/i6kyb2t/
Advises:

Take several points out of self-replication and put them into Speed, Exploration, and Combat. It wouldn't hurt to have 5-6 in each of those categories. If you want, you could put one point into factory, harvest drone, and wire drone, too, but you don't really need any more of those until later anyway.

But that's with 30 Trust.
The only other way to do this without deprioritizing anything, might be to try and buy as many Threnodies as you can to try and get enough Honor fast enough to buy more Trust?

Thank you, but if I add points to combat and deprioritize something else my number of drones decreases very quickly, and if I take points off of production my drones become bored and stop duplicating.

@MasonKou - Well, at this point you have to eat a loss of some kind. The only thing you can do is kill drifters faster than they arrive. Worst case is losing all your probes then making Full Combat ones manually to take as many drifters out with each new probe? Drifters don't self-replicate, they are just losses from your own probes?

@MasonKou - https://universalpaperclips.fandom.com/wiki/Probes - has a chart for Hazard Remediation. I'd put 2 or 3 points in at best right now. Hope you figure out a solution soon! If you want to update your question with more screenshots, that might help?

The top picture is a screenshot of what I'm at right now, after buying more Threnodies

@MasonKou - Awesome! Almost winning a battle and close to buying more Current Trust to match your Max and get better combat! May you win (more?) soon and your probe count increase! Goodnight to me!
